# Creating and uploading zip to s3 getting stuck

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

In an AWS S3 bucket, there are multiple files (unknown number). I have a requirement where my node.js code will zip all those files into a single zip and then upload it back into the same bucket. I am using the "archiver" module to get individual objects, zip it and upload it back into s3 using streams. Following is the code snippet of the Zipping and Upload program:

```
//s3Contents is the output of listV2Command 
public async zipAllFiles(s3Contents:_Object[]){
        try{
            const archive=archiver('zip');
            archive.on('error', (err)=>{
                console.log(`Encountered error while zipping: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
                throw(err);
            });


            const upload=new Upload({
                client:this.s3Client,
                params:{
                    Bucket:process.env.BUCKET_KEY,
                    Key:`${this.folderName}/${this.jobId}.zip`,
                    Body:Readable.from(archive)
                }
            });
            for(let i=0;i<s3Contents.length;i++){
                const getParams={
                    Bucket:process.env.BUCKET_KEY,
                    Key:s3Contents[i].Key
                };
                const objectData=await this.getObjectFromS3(getParams); //This uses a different pool of S3Clients
                
                if(objectData.Body!==undefined){
                    const splitFolderAndFiles=s3Contents[i].Key?.split("/");
                    if(splitFolderAndFiles===undefined)
                        return;

                    const renderedFileName=splitFolderAndFiles[splitFolderAndFiles?.length-1];
                    console.log(`Appending: ${renderedFileName}`);
                    archive.append(objectData.Body as unknown as Readable, { name: renderedFileName || '' });;
                }
            }
            archive.finalize();
            
            

            this.logToCloudWatch('Uploading!!');
            await upload.done();
            
            this.logToCloudWatch('Put the zip successfully into s3');
        }catch(err){
            console.log('Zipping error');
            this.logToCloudWatch(`Error while zipping: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
        }
    }
```

Now, when the number of objects are few (about 50-100), then this works as expected, reads from s3, zips it and uploads it back into the s3 bucket. But when the number of objects increases (224 objects, each of 1MB), it gets stuck waiting for upload.done(). And I have tried waiting for half an hour for it to resolve, but it didn't resolve. No sense in waiting any longer, as even if it resolves, the turnaround time is too much to be of any use. To be honest, I don't understand the Upload from @aws-sdk/lib-storage completely.
If someone could point out to me what is wrong with this approach of mine, then I would be grateful. Thanks...

Comment: Be aware of third-party libraries that do this e.g. [aws-s3-zipper](https://github.com/DanielHindi/aws-s3-zipper).